# When reboot android mobile phone I am not getting notification in android studio

Tags: java, android

I want notification when reboot android mobile phone. But when run application notification show. i Implement all permission. so please anyone help me. I am struck for three day. Please help me.

```
public class BeaconService extends Service {
    public BeaconService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        showNotification()
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.v(TAG, "service destroyed");
    }
    private void showNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_loc)
                        .setContentTitle("Welcome to Ford Show Room")
                        .setContentText("Hello Puneet, Welcome to Ford! You'll be shortly attended by Karthik! ")
                        .setPriority(2)
                        .setOnlyAlertOnce(false);
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(2001, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

AutoBeaconNotifyReceiver.java

```
public class AutoBeaconNotifyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION)) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, BeaconService.class);
            context.startService(myIntent);
        }
    }
```

menifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      <service android:name="com.kontakt.sdk.android.ble.service.ProximityService" android:exported="false"/>    
   <receiver android:name=".AutoBeaconNotifyReceiver" android:label="BeaconNotifyReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

Comment: try  with "<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />" hope it will work for you

Comment: @Rushabh042 where i have set <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

Comment: check your service is registered in manifest or not?

Comment: @AvaniNagar yes its registered  <service android:name=".BeaconService"/>

Comment: You need to relplace that line instead of this line "<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />"

Comment: @Rushabh042 I tried this "<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />" but not working

Comment: Service will tack some time to start it after reboot device so just wait for few minutes.

Comment: @Rushabh042 I replaced still not working

Comment: try with add this in <receiver section android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105134/discussion-between-alam-and-rushabh042).

Comment: You also need to make return START_STICKY; in onStartCommand instead of your Code @Alam

Comment: @Rushabh042  use return START_STICKY; in onStartCommand still not working

Comment: @Rushabh042 My Question is when i killed app yet i will get notification from service.